# Are WCF Web services compatible with Sharepoint?

Tags: wcf, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to place a dataview webPart on a WSS page through Sharepoint designer, consuming a WCF Web service, buth when I place the WSDL of my Web Service, it gives me an error.  I migrated the WS to ASP.Net WS and it work perfectly.

The error is related to the Soap envelope.  I am using anonymous consumption for now (don't want to add complexity to the task)

Is there something I have to do on WCF to make it 'compatible' with WSS?

Comment: what's the error?  how do you have the WCF service configured? Are you using the basicHttpBinding?

Comment: Cheeso: I;ve just added more detail to the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default OOTB you can't consume a WCF service through SharePoint Designer (afaik).

However ["Consume WCF service using Sharepoint Designer"](http://www.afanaat.nl/index.php/2008/10/23/consume-wcf-service-using-sharepoint-designer/) describes a workaround to adjust the datasource so you can read it in SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Thanks Mundeep. It seems the link you provided has the answer to my question!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to put a WCF web service within SharePoint, right?  If that is the case I ran into just this problem recently.  You basically have two approaches:

1. Transforming SharePoint's web.config such that it can use full-blown WCF.
2. Write your own HTTP Handler with minimal (if any) changes to the SharePoint web.config.

I have opted for the latter, but go into detail on both at the ThreeWill SharePoint Depth wiki here: [Hosting WCF-like REST and JSON Services in SharePoint](http://wiki.threewill.com/display/enterprise/Hosting+WCF-like+REST+and+JSON+Services+in+SharePoint).

Comment: I would opt for Kirk´s solution. SPD is great for trying out the concept but if you are really going to have your "code" installable use a feature that "changes" your web.config to support WCF.

Comment: My response is several years old (and yes, the link is unfortunately unavailable).  If you are using SharePoint 2010 you can do WCF.  If you must use SharePoint 2007 (it can work with SP2010 too) then an HTTPHandler may be your answer.